# How to test page load with Google Chrome extension and without Google Chrome extension

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that blocks pages set by admin.

I need to test website load speed with and without my extension but I cannot find any tools for it.
My extension is only getting URL of webpage & all the logic is done on external server so it should not affect webpage load but I still need to test it.

I have tried with Lighthouse but that isn not providing any useful data.

Or maybe any tools that will measure time when page is blocked?

Comment: Edit: Yes if I want to measure how long extension needs to block page I can just modify code.

Comment: Why don't you just use Chrome's enterprise group policy options to use a blacklist instead, or let a firewall handle this? A user can just run in Incognito mode to circumvent the extension.

Comment: That was not even a question. User cannot run incognito if it is disabled (chromebooks)

Comment: Right, so if you are already using registry settings to disable Incognito mode, use the same registry settings to use a whitelist or blacklist.